# groovy.lang.Binding difference between property and variable

Tags: java, groovy

Couldn't really figure out/find what a difference between thouse two

```
import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        Integer p = 1,
                v = 1;
        binding.setProperty("p", p);
        binding.setVariable("v", v);

        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
        shell.evaluate("p++;v++;");
        System.out.println(String.format("BINDING Property = %s, Variable = %s", binding.getProperty("p"), binding.getVariable("v")));
        System.out.println(String.format("JAVA Property = %s, Variable = %s", p, v));
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
BINDING Property = 2, Variable = 2
JAVA Property = 1, Variable = 1
```

Is there is some purpose for using one or another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `groovy.lang.Binding` overloads `setProperty` and `getProperty` methods so you can access variables using field accessor or subscript operator. If you take a look at the source code of these two methods you will find something like this:

```
/**
 * Overloaded to make variables appear as bean properties or via the subscript operator
 */
public Object getProperty(String property) {
    /** @todo we should check if we have the property with the metaClass instead of try/catch  */
    try {
        return super.getProperty(property);
    }
    catch (MissingPropertyException e) {
        return getVariable(property);
    }
}

/**
 * Overloaded to make variables appear as bean properties or via the subscript operator
 */
public void setProperty(String property, Object newValue) {
    /** @todo we should check if we have the property with the metaClass instead of try/catch  */
    try {
        super.setProperty(property, newValue);
    }
    catch (MissingPropertyException e) {
        setVariable(property, newValue);
    }
}
```

It means that in Groovy you could express

```java
binding.setVariable("v", v);
```

as

```groovy
binding.v = v
// or
binding['v'] = v
```

Of course if the property you are accessing with `setProperty` or `getProperty` exists in the class, then you won't be able to set a variable using this name and in this case, you need to call `binding.setVariable()` directly.

On the other hand, methods `getVariable` and `setVariable` reads or puts values directly to the internal map. Here is what its source code looks like:

```java
/**
 * @param name the name of the variable to lookup
 * @return the variable value
 */
public Object getVariable(String name) {
    if (variables == null)
        throw new MissingPropertyException(name, this.getClass());

    Object result = variables.get(name);

    if (result == null && !variables.containsKey(name)) {
        throw new MissingPropertyException(name, this.getClass());
    }

    return result;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the given variable
 *
 * @param name  the name of the variable to set
 * @param value the new value for the given variable
 */
public void setVariable(String name, Object value) {
    if (variables == null)
        variables = new LinkedHashMap();
    variables.put(name, value);
}
```

Comment: `The class groovy.lang.Binding overloads setProperty and getProperty methods` 
That was confusing part. Somehow I dint't check source code before questioning.